# Checkboxlist applying If statements

Tags: vb.net

I am stating VB and since it is so close to VBScript I have been having fun with it. But now I have come across the "Checkboxlist".

My boss saw me making a Windows Forms Application and asked me to make him a interface (GUI) for one of his batch files. In the batch you start by choosing between lines 1 through 10 and it does the rest. So I made a Checkboxlist and made check-boxes going from 1 to 10. Now I am not sure how to tell it that when I click a button a if statement looks at what has been checked and take to appropriate action.

I think i am suppose to start with something like

```
If CheckedListBox1.Items() = True then
```

But i know this does not work. 
Anything thing will help.
Thank you.

Comment: VB.NET is nothing like VBScript.  `.Items()` is a collection of the things in the CLB, testing if it is True is meaningless.  Are you trying to see which item is checked?  Might want to [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looking for more of a "this has been selected so do this". I want it so if Line one is selected then is will type line one in the batch with Sendkeys. I will have a look. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: `For Each checkedItem In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) event. This event is fired when the checked state of an item changes.

```
Private Sub HandleCheckedListBox1ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    Dim item As Object = Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Item(e.Index)
    Dim text As String = Me.CheckedListBox1.GetItemText(item)

    Select Case e.CurrentValue
        Case CheckState.Unchecked
            '...
        Case CheckState.Checked
            '...
        Case CheckState.Indeterminate
            '...
    End Select

End Sub
```

Or iterate all checked items:

```
Private Sub HandleButton1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each item As Object In Me.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Dim text As String = Me.CheckedListBox1.GetItemText(item)
        '...
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: the OP only wants it to fire when the user clicks on a button, so should use the btn_click event and then loops through and check: if checkbox.checked=true then....

Comment: You're probably right, that's why I included the `Iterate all checked items` part. But I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: So lets see if i understand this. When the button is clicked it looks through all of the items I have in CheckedListBox1 and makes a text string out of it. Then I define them? Sorry new area for me.

Comment: @Alenhj It loops through each item in the `CheckedItems` collection and gets the string representation of the specified item as seen on screen. What you do with this string is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to have multiply checked boxes run the same thing in order, but I am on my way.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå I don't suppose you know where I can find a good example for beginner to open a batch file and sent a command to it with VB.net without the dreaded Sendkeys function?